# importxml xpath div how to get the info when neither class nor id?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

using Importxml in google sheets.

How can I get "data-film-id" and "data-film-release-year" from this, when the info isn't a div class or a div id?:

```
<div class="react-component film-poster film-poster-193260 poster linked-film-poster -attributed" 

data-component-class="globals.comps.FilmPosterComponent" 
data-film-id="193260" 
data-film-name="The Choice" 
data-poster-url="/film/the-choice-1987/image-150/" 
data-film-release-year="1987" 
data-film-link="/film/the-choice-1987/"
```

I was able to get some info from the site (where A1 is [https://letterboxd.com/tag/30-countries-2018/diary/by/added/page/58/]) into google sheets using this:

```
=ImportXML(A1, "//div[contains(@class,'react-component') and contains(@class,'film-poster')]/a/@href")
```

So I know everything works, but that's only because the href is below that div in its own paragraph. My issue is trying to dig into the info that is being displayed above.

After searching on this site I tried this (among many other things) but it resulted in an error.

```
=ImportXML(A1, "//li[@class='poster-container']//div[not(@id) or not(@class)]")
```

But it gives me info I already have, not the info I need.

Maybe I can't get the date because it isn't a class or an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [attribute selector](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp).

```
=ImportXML(A1, "//div[contains(@class,'react-component') and contains(@class,'film-poster')]/attribute::data-film-id")
```

So in Column B you can have the above formula to display the film ID, in Column C another formula for the release year, and so on.

If you want it all in one row, which I don't recommend, it would be

```
=ImportXML(A1, "//div[contains(@class,'react-component') and contains(@class,'film-poster')]/attribute::data-film-id | //div[contains(@class,'react-component') and contains(@class,'film-poster')]/attribute::data-film-release-year")
```

I don't recommend combining this because it outputs everything in one column "year, id, year, id, ...". Very messy.